# Understanding solution to online test

Tags: dynamic-programming

The question is in the following link:
http://www.spoj.com/problems/AEROLITE/

Input:

```
    1 1 1 1
    0 0 6 3
    1 1 1 2
    [and 7 test cases more]
```

Output:

```
    6
    57
    8
    [and 7 test cases more]
```

How does the output come from the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the outputs corresponding to the following letters:

a. 1 1 1 1 = 6

b. 0 0 6 3 = 57

c. 1 1 1 2 = 8

Restating the definitions from the problem in a more tactical way, the 4 inputs correspond to the following:

1. The number of "{}" pairs
2. The number of "[]" pairs
3. The number of "()" pairs
4. The max depth when generating the output

The output is a single number representing the number of regular expressions that match the input parameters (how much depth can be used with the pairs) and how many combinations of the 3 pairs can be generating matching the prioritization rules that "()" cannot contain "{}" or "[]" and "[]" cannot contain "{}".

The walkthrough below shows how to arrive at the outputs, but it doesn't try to break the sub-problems or anything down. Hopefully, it will at least help you connect the numbers and start to find the problems to break down.

Taking those examples explicitly, start with "a" for `1 1 1 1 = 6`:

- The inputs mean that only do a depth of 1 and use 1 pair each of "{}", "[]", "()". This is a permutation how many arrangements of 3 can be made as permutations, so 3! = 6.
- Actual: {}, {}()[], []{}(), {}, (){}[], ()[]{}

Then go to "b" for `1 1 1 2 = 8`

- This is just like "a" with exception that we must now allow for another level of depth (d = 2 instead of 1)
- Therefore, this is 6 from "a" + any additional combinations of depth = 2
  ** Additional = {[()]}, {} (only 2 additional cases meet the rules)
- "a" + (additional for d = 2) = 8

Finally, consider "b" where we are exploring only the d = 3 of 6 "()".

- We must break down and add the depth (d) of 1, 2, and 3
- Because only parenthesis exist here, this is just a Catalan number Cn where n = 6, but limited to a depth of no more than 3 levels of parenthesis (For more on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)  C(6) = 132, but once you exclude all the Catalan numbers for depths more than 3, you are left with 57 matches.
- Alternatively and much more tediously, you can iterate over all the combinations of parenthesis that are depth of 3 or less to get to 57 records:
  ** Start with d = 1, so just ()()()()()()
  ** Then d = 2, so examples like (())()()()(), ()(())()()(), ()()(())()(), ()()()(())(), ()()()()(()), and so on
  ** Then d = 3, so examples like ((()))()()(), ()((()))()(), ()()((()))(), ()()()((())), and so on

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining! :)

Comment: Can you please explain me how this output came? 8 0 11 3 2845

Comment: Very similar to the tedious iteration, you limit your depth to 3, then get all the combinations of 8 brackets and 11 parentheses supporting depths up to 3 that are limited so that no brackets are contained within a parentheses. I'm purposefully staying away from the DP sub-problems - it's been a very long time since my algorithms classes :) You can probably get better help getting started in solving your recurrence in the "math" community (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming)